# Correctly using xml.dom.minidom reading xml with python 2.4

Tags: python, xml

i have a an xml file that includes the following information that i need to get from from it.
For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Temperature>
    <HPA>42.0</HPA>
    <IF>48.1</IF>
    <Modem>55.6</Modem>
</Temperature>
```

i have found a few explanations on how to use the xml.dom.minidom but no matter what example i try i get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.grobman\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 26, in ?
from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_vars
File "C:\Users\michael.grobman\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.5.0.201701191708\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 591
get_label = lambda label: str(label) if not isinstance(label, tuple) else '/'.join(map(str, label))
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i have even took a full example code for the sake of the test and it still fails.

i am restricted to python 2.4 as that is what the system runs.
i cant seem to understand what am i missing... 
(i wish i knew how to import etree into 2.4 would have made my life a lot easier)

Edit :

Found this in my code :

```
parsed = []
for i in range(0, len(cords)):
    n = -1
    temp = cords[i][n:] + ' ' + cords[i][:n]
    temp = list(temp)
    for y in range(0, len(temp)):
       if temp[y] == chr(176) or temp[y] == chr(39):
            temp[y] = ' '
            temp = ''.join(temp)
    parsed.append(temp)
return parsed
```

to what i can replace the "if" to make it work the same as it is now?

Comment: Python 2.4 doesn't have `… if … else …` support. Use `… and … or …` construct. Your PyDev isn't old enough.

Comment: edited the code with my code issue, im very unfamiliar with 2.4 so i did not knew it does not use if else...

Comment: I have found the issue and fixed it, but you are wrong about 2.4 not having is/else/elif as i am using them in 2.4

Comment: No, **Conditional expressions** were introduced in Python 2.5 with the [PEP308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/). See [change log](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions).

Comment: Well no argument there, still works though with 2.4.